# can't make round corners for UIView

Tags: swift, user-interface, uikit

I have a UIView object inside a horizontal stackView.
I'm calling this function inside LayoutSubviews:

```
     func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CurveRadius) {
        var r = CGFloat()
        switch radius {
        case .small:
            r = self.frame.width / 30
        case .medium:
            r = self.frame.width / 25
        }
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: r, height: r))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask
    }
```

but it just doesn't work. I guess it has something to do with a stackView. can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

```
extension UIView {
    /// Rounds ``UIView`` corners.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - maskedCorners: Corners to be rounded.
    ///   - cornerRadius: Value to be set as corner radius.
    func roundCorners(maskedCorners: CACornerMask,
                      cornerRadius: CGFloat) {
        layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        layer.maskedCorners = maskedCorners
        layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the `UIStackView` is the problem here, but there's another, more re-usable way to do this using a `CACornerMask` on the `UIView`'s `layer` in an `extension`:

```swift
extension UIView {
    func roundCorners() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        self.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
    }
}
```

When you create your view, just call the `roundCorners()`, like this:

```swift
private lazy var roundCorneredView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        view.roundCorners()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
```

Then add that view to your hierarchy in the usual way using `addSubview`.

[CACornerMask docs @ Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/2877488-maskedcorners)